# Stuck in a loop after login in 14.04

Tags: bash, openvpn

I am a Linux beginner so bear with me please.

I used a bash script to automatically re-connect to OpenVPN. It worked fine when I ran it.
http://www.gabsoftware.com/tips/automatically-reconnect-to-your-vpn-on-linux/

Then, I changed my `~/.profile` to automatically execute the script.
Now when I try to login to my desktop nothing happens. Doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> shows:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: no valid VPN secrets.
```

I have no idea how to stop the process. It's on an endless loop where it fails to connect every 10 seconds. Doing <kbd>SysRq</kbd> sequences only shows `processID quit`. Is there a way out? Ideally, I would like to keep my user directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Error: Connection activation failed: no valid VPN secrets' might be caused due to the issue with login user privilege. So try to edit the following,

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION_NAME
```

After doing this change the password-flags=0 instead of 1 then add your password.

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=YourPassword
```

Start the VPN connection with  `sudo nmcli con up id ConnectionName` and this will help you to fix the problem.

Comment: I could only edit the file from recovery menu. I edited the file as you suggested but now it seems my original connection is gone. The configuration file is still in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ , but the actual connection doesn't get listed when I do nmcli con. It no longer has a UUID which is a problem because my script references the connection through that.

Comment: I did figure out how to edit my ~/.profile file from the recovery menu however, thanks to your suggestion. I am still curious to know if there is a way to get out of that loop without the recovery? Is there a way to terminate a program that's spitting out errors and won't allow me to input a command?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It seems if you want to run these scripts, it's best to edit your OpenVPN configuration files before you log out the way it was described by vembutech. In my case I was also missing the the control operator(ampersand) at the end which caused the infinite loop.